# Elasticsearch time field and range query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to save time fields in elastic search, in format like HH:mm and search then based on some time query range like HH:mm-HH:mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store time in elastic in this format check the related doc about the different date format here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

```
 hour_minute or strict_hour_minute
    A formatter for a two digit hour of day and two digit minute of hour: HH:mm.
```

You will have a mapping like this if you use the build in format:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "hour_minute"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To search you can use the build in format in your range query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "gte" : "10:15",
                "lte" : "20:13",
                "format" : "hour_minute"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)